# How to prevent multiple Multiple Api calls

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web, video.js

I am using a library video js with react. For getting the watch time of a video. I am getting the watch time properly and Api is working fine but the issue is when I move to the next video or I change the page while watching video, the Api is called multiple times. I want it to make a request only one time. I am using the following code.

```js
 useEffect(()=>{

        const videoElement = videoRef.current;

      const player = playerRef.current = videojs(videoElement, options, () => {
                 console.log(player?.currentTime())
    
                player.on("timeupdate", function () 
                     player.on('dispose', (e) => {

                           console.log(e)
                           e.preventDefault()
dispatch(getWatchTime({userId:user?._id,videoId:watch?._id,watchTime:player.currentTime()}))
                
     })
                
    });
   })
      },[])
```

Comment: You’re adding a “dispose” handler on every “timeupdate” event; that seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Im getting the watch time using player.currentTime() which comes with  player.on("timeUpdate). Im using dispose because I want to send the watch time of video to backend when the user navigates from  the current video or moves to next screen.

Comment: … Every time there’s a “timeupdate” event you add an additional “dispose” handler. This means on the “dispose” event you dispatch as many “getWatchTime” actions as there’s been “timeupdate” events.

Comment: thanks for replying. Can you please modify the code? Because, getCurrentTime() is only accessible in "timeUpdate"